# Gandi API : Create domain error on test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I'm actually working on the test environment of Gandi.
I'm using the gandi gem (https://github.com/veilleperso/gandi)
I can connect with my API key etc... but when I want to create a new domain :

```
domain_spec = {
    'owner' => 'FLN123-GANDI',
    'admin' => 'FLN123-GANDI',
    'bill' => 'FLN123-GANDI',
    'tech' => 'FLN123-GANDI',
    'nameservers' => ['a.dns.gandi-ote.net', 'b.dns.gandi-ote.net',
                  'c.dns.gandi-ote.net'],
    'duration' => 1
    }
@api.domain.create('foo.fr', domain_spec)
```

I got this message :

> Error on object : OBJECT_CONTACT (CAUSE_INVALID) [Your are not the owner of the domain nor a reseller]

Comment: Are you the owner of the domain `foo.fr`? Otherwise the error message _"Your are not the owner of the domain"_ just might make sense?

Comment: `foo.fr` is juste a example, I'll use an other in my code but I'm the owner on the production environment, but in test environment we have to create a domain and it doesn't work. I don't know if it's clear for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can only create domains  in both OTE and production environment which wasn't registered.

The OTE is not an empty sandbox, it's based on the data from production environment.